# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notifications not firing when run app first time

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have called this line of code in the init method and viewDidLoad method. However, the method applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification NEVER fires on the first time I run the app. It only runs after I have run it once.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
          selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveNotificationAction)
                           name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Is this right? Is there a way for my viewController to be notified of UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification the first time I run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it won't be fired when you first time run the APP

```
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Posted when the application becomes active.
An application is active when it is receiving events. An active application can be said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, and gains focus when the device is unlocked.
```

you can just fire it youself after the APP is initialised.

Comment: it actually does fire during startup.   Maybe the OP is subscribing to it after the notification is initially posted.   Even your quote from the documentation is pretty clear:  "It gains focus after being launched"